# JBOSS messaging replicated queue

Tags: jboss, jms, messaging

I am using JBOSS messaging in the following way:

1) Two JBOSS instances using 'all' config (i.e. clustered config)

2) One replicated queue created on each JBOSS instance wiht same JNDI name (clustered = true)

3) one producer attach locally to the queue on each instance (i.e. both the producer on both the nodes keep on adding messages to this replicated queue)

4) One JBOSS instance is marked as "consumer node" and queue message consumer is started on only this node (i.e. messages will be consumed on only one node). There is a logic which will decide which JBOSS instance is marked as "consumer node"

5) PostOffice used is clustered

6) server peer configured to not enforce message sequencing.

7) produced messages are non-persistent (deliveryMode = NON_PERSISTENT)

But I am facing problem with this. Messages produced on "non consumer node" do not get replicated to the queue on the "consumer node" and hence not available for consumption.

I enabled the logging and checked that postoffice finds two queues but only delivers to the local queue as it discovers that the remote queue is recoverable.

Any idea how to set it working?

FYI: I believe a message can be delivered to only one queue (local or remote). So, I want only one queue which is distributed but I am currently getting 2 different distributed queues (however their JNDI name is same). Is this a problem? If yes, how to solve this? Weblogic provides the option of creating a queue on admin server and thus a shared queue is possible there. What is the similar mechanism in JBOSS messaging? Or should I need to approach this problem as 2 queues which are synchronized. If yes, then how to achieve synchronization between them?

Thanks for taking out sometime to help me!!

Regards